# How to refork my current main file to follow an object-oriented style?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm writing an application with PyQt. Since I should stick to an object-oriented programming, my main file should be fixed to follow that. Also, because I would like to use Signals and Slots, and I will have some trouble to implement them later, better to fix it now before my current code gets more complex.

As you can see in my code, I just have an exec_() method, but is not inside in a `if __name__ == "__main__":`

I shouldn't be asking this, but in my current code the main widget is a custom class which inherits QGraphicsView. In all the examples that I read, the main class are QDialogs,QWidgets or QMainWindow, then in an if statement executes the application.

Here it is my current code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from dragbutton import DragButton
from wiringgraphicsview import *
import collections 

import icons_rc

app = QApplication([])

scene = MyScene()
menu = QMenu()
widget_container = QWidget()

#dictonaries for dragbuttons (used later for connecting them)
jacks_dic = {}
inputs_dic = collections.OrderedDict()
wire_dic = {}

#AIF1RX (PLAYBACK CONTROLS)

# put a button into the scene and move it
btn_AIF1RX1 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1RX1.setObjectName("btn_AIF1RX1")
btn_AIF1RX1.setAllowDrag(True) #Allow Drag n Drop of DragButton
btn_AIF1RX1.setAcceptDrops(False)
btn_AIF1RX1.setGeometry(QRect(-100, 50, 51, 31)) #Set dimensions of it
#Set icon of button1
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/audio-input-line.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1RX1.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1RX1.setFlat(False)
btn_AIF1RX1.setMenu(menu)
#jacks_array.append(btn_AIF1RX1)

btn_AIF1RX2 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1RX2.setObjectName("btn_AIF1RX2")
btn_AIF1RX2.setGeometry(QRect(200, -50, 51, 31)) #Set dimensions of it
btn_AIF1RX2.setAllowDrag(True) #Allow Drag n Drop of DragButton
btn_AIF1RX2.setAcceptDrops(False)
#Set input line icon
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/audio-input-line.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1RX2.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1RX2.setFlat(False)
btn_AIF1RX2.setMenu(menu)
#jacks_array.append(btn_AIF1RX2)

#Create Layouts for AIF1RX
AIF1RX_main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
AIF1RX_layout = QHBoxLayout()
AIF1RX1_layout = QVBoxLayout()
AIF1RX2_layout = QVBoxLayout()

#Create Labels for AIF1RXl
lbl_playback = QLabel("Playback From RPi")
lbl_AIF1RX1_L = QLabel("L")
AIF1RX1_layout.addWidget(lbl_AIF1RX1_L)
lbl_AIF1RX2_R = QLabel("R")
AIF1RX2_layout.addWidget(lbl_AIF1RX2_R)
lbl_AIF1RX1 = QLabel("AIF1RX1")
AIF1RX1_layout.addWidget( lbl_AIF1RX1 )
lbl_AIF1RX2 = QLabel("AIF1RX2")
AIF1RX2_layout.addWidget( lbl_AIF1RX2 )


#fit AIF1RX layouts
AIF1RX_main_layout.addWidget( lbl_playback )
AIF1RX_main_layout.addLayout(AIF1RX_layout)
AIF1RX_layout.addLayout(AIF1RX1_layout)
AIF1RX_layout.addLayout(AIF1RX2_layout)

AIF1RX1_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1RX1)
AIF1RX2_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1RX2)


#AIF1TX (RECORD INPUTS)

btn_AIF1TX1_1 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX1_1.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX1_1")
#This button shoudn't be dragged, it is just for dropping.
btn_AIF1TX1_1.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX1_1.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX1_1.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX1_1.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX1_1'] = None

btn_AIF1TX1_2 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX1_2.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX1_2")
btn_AIF1TX1_2.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX1_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX1_2.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX1_2.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX1_2'] = None

btn_AIF1TX1_3 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX1_3.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX1_3")
btn_AIF1TX1_3.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX1_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX1_3.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX1_3.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX1_3'] = None


btn_AIF1TX1_4 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX1_4.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX1_4")
btn_AIF1TX1_4.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX1_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX1_4.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX1_4.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX1_4'] = None

btn_AIF1TX2_1 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX2_1.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX2_1")
btn_AIF1TX2_1.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX2_1.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX2_1.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX2_1.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX2_1'] = None

btn_AIF1TX2_2 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX2_2.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX2_2")
btn_AIF1TX2_2.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX2_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX2_2.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX2_2.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX2_2'] = None

btn_AIF1TX2_3 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX2_3.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX2_3")
btn_AIF1TX2_3.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX2_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX2_3.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX2_3.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX2_3'] = None

btn_AIF1TX2_4 = DragButton()
btn_AIF1TX2_4.setObjectName("btn_AIF1TX2_4")
btn_AIF1TX2_4.setAllowDrag(False)
btn_AIF1TX2_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/input_small.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
btn_AIF1TX2_4.setIcon(icon)
btn_AIF1TX2_4.setFixedWidth(16)
inputs_dic['AIF1TX2_4'] = None

#Create Layouts for AIF1TX
AIF1TX_main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
AIF1TX_layout = QHBoxLayout()
AIF1TX1_layout = QVBoxLayout()
AIF1TX2_layout = QVBoxLayout()
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout = QHBoxLayout()
AIF1TX2_inputs_layout = QHBoxLayout()

#Create Labels for AIF1TX
lbl_record = QLabel("Record to RPi")
lbl_AIF1TX1_L = QLabel("L")
AIF1TX1_layout.addWidget(lbl_AIF1TX1_L)
lbl_AIF1TX2_R = QLabel("R")
AIF1TX2_layout.addWidget(lbl_AIF1TX2_R)
lbl_AIF1TX1 = QLabel("AIF1TX1")
AIF1TX1_layout.addWidget( lbl_AIF1TX1 )
lbl_AIF1TX2 = QLabel("AIF1TX2")
AIF1TX2_layout.addWidget( lbl_AIF1TX2 )

#fit AIF1TX layouts
AIF1TX_main_layout.addWidget( lbl_record )
AIF1TX_main_layout.addLayout(AIF1TX_layout)
AIF1TX_layout.addLayout(AIF1TX1_layout)
AIF1TX_layout.addLayout(AIF1TX2_layout)
AIF1TX1_layout.addLayout(AIF1TX1_inputs_layout)
AIF1TX2_layout.addLayout(AIF1TX2_inputs_layout)

#Inputs
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_1)
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_2)
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_3)
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_4)
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout.setSpacing(0)
AIF1TX1_inputs_layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)

AIF1TX2_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_1)
AIF1TX2_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_2)
AIF1TX2_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_3)
AIF1TX2_inputs_layout.addWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_4)
AIF1TX2_inputs_layout.setSpacing(0)
AIF1TX2_inputs_layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)

#Wrap Playback/Record controls into a layout
record_playback_layouts = QHBoxLayout(widget_container)
record_playback_layouts.addLayout(AIF1RX_main_layout)
record_playback_layouts.addLayout(AIF1TX_main_layout)
#widget_container.setFixedWidth(290)

widget_scene = scene.addWidget(widget_container)

# Instantiate our own proxy which forwars drag/drop events to the child widget
#of AIFTX

proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_1 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_1.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_1)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_1.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_1)
#
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_2 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_2.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_2)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_2)

proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_3 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_3.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_3)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_3)

proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_4 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_4.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX1_4)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX1_4)

proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_1 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_1.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_1)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_1.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_1)

proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_2 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_2.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_2)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_2)

proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_3 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_3.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_3)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_3)

proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_4 = ProxyWidget() 
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_4.setWidget(btn_AIF1TX2_4)
proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
scene.addItem(proxy_btn_AIF1TX2_4)

@pyqtSlot(str)
def on_connect(self,  input):
    print 'connected'
    jack_connector = self.sender().parent().objectName() #sender's parent of QAction should be the button
    wire_dic['wire_1'] = Wire(  jack_connector , widget_container.findChild( DragButton,  'btn_' + input ) , None, scene)

#Load Menu options for Jacks dragbuttons

#create sub-menus
submenus_dic = collections.OrderedDict()
submenus_dic['AIF1TX1_submenu'] = QMenu("AIF1TX1 (L) Record to RPi")
submenus_dic['AIF1TX2_submenu'] = QMenu("AIF1TX2 (R) Record to RPi")


actions_dic = collections.OrderedDict()
for input   in inputs_dic:
    #Create an Action
    actions_dic[ input  ] = QtGui.QAction( input, None)
    actions_dic[ input ].triggered[()].connect( lambda input=input:  on_connect(actions_dic[ input  ], input)  )


    #Condition to add to a submenu
    if input[:-2] == 'AIF1TX1' :
        submenus_dic['AIF1TX1_submenu'].addAction( actions_dic[ input ] )

    if input[:-2] == 'AIF1TX2' :
        submenus_dic['AIF1TX2_submenu'].addAction( actions_dic[ input ] )

#Add SubMenus to Main Menu
for submenu in submenus_dic:
    menu.addMenu(submenus_dic[ submenu ] )

# Create the view using the scene
view = WiringGraphicsView(None, scene)
view.show()
view.setWindowTitle("Device Advanced Mixer")

app.exec_()
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Identify parts of your app that can usefully be split off into classes, and do that.

In the past when faced with converting non-OO to OO I have found it easiest to start one by one - don't try to do it all in one go - and then having made a good start sit back and consider if the approach makes the best sense. If you can see areas where you're using the same code pattern multiple times, see if you can usefully share it in a base class. However, don't share unless the items are actually related. It is always useful to remember.

If:

- two classes are related by 'X is-a Y', then it's possible you can make X a subclass of Y.
- two classes are related by 'X has a Y', then you should not subclass, but Y should probably be a member object within X.

Remember, there is no 'right' way, there are just ways that work. Your task as a programmer is to find the way that works and is comprehensible not just for you but for others too.

Ideally, it's also extensible, easy to debug and optimial, but that comes with time!

HTH

Comment: Actually, the classes are well-defined. Except in this file. I should create a class for the entire application file...